# Alignment of tables in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

How do I place 3 different tables -  L1, L2, R1 in the specified below position:

1. L1 on Top Left - 2 rows
2. L2 **immediately below** L1 on the Left - 2 rows.
3. R1 on the Top Right  - This has 10 rows

The issue is L2 is placed way below L1 as it is inline, how can I make it appear right below L1? Should float left / right or any other setting can help me achieve this?

https://jsfiddle.net/cyppyntp/4/

```
<table class="one" id="L1">
    <tr>
        <th>Month-1</th>
        <th>Savings-1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="one" id="L2">
    <tr>
        <th>Month-2</th>
        <th>Savings-2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>March</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>April</td>
        <td>$600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>May</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>June</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>August</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sep</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Oct</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nov</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="two" id="R1">
    <tr>
        <th>Month-3</th>
        <th>Savings-3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>December</td>
        <td>$400</td>
    </tr>
</table>

.inlineTable {
display: inline-block;
}
table.one {
width:45%;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}
table.two {    
text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Are you unable or unwilling to change the order of the tables in your markup?

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/cyppyntp/6/) what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/cyppyntp/6/)

I've changed the order of your tables slightly. Also, I have added two new divs. See the HTML below

```
<div class="left">
    <table class="one">
        <tr>
            <th>Month-1</th>
            <th>Savings-1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>January</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="two">
        <tr>
            <th>Month-3</th>
            <th>Savings-3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>December</td>
            <td>$400</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <table class="one">
        <tr>
            <th>Month-2</th>
            <th>Savings-2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>January</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>March</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>April</td>
            <td>$600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>May</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>June</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>August</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sep</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Oct</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nov</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And, also added the below given CSS

```
.left,.right{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lal. This is what i want.

Comment: Thankyou.. @user3921458

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of floats, but they work here without any change to your markup other than class values. You could accomplish the same without even that by using a `:first-child` selector.

```css
.inlineTable {
  display: inline-block;
}
table {
  width: 45%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
table.left {
  float: left;
}
table.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<table class="left">
  <tr>
    <th>Month-1</th>
    <th>Savings-1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="right">
  <tr>
    <th>Month-2</th>
    <th>Savings-2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>April</td>
    <td>$600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>May</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>June</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>August</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sep</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oct</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nov</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="left">
  <tr>
    <th>Month-3</th>
    <th>Savings-3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>December</td>
    <td>$400</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/cyppyntp/7/)**

Comment: Thanks, that is quiet simple solution. Thank You.